# List/Search all existing UTIs (Uniform Type Identifiers)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, uti

Is it possible to find a list of all existing [Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html) on a system?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about

```
 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump
```

Even better: A Graph of all Universal Type Identifiers - [Kevin Ballard's Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160527232247/http://kevin.sb.org/2006/03/16/graph-of-all-universal-type-identifiers/)

Comment: Just the UTIs: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump | grep '[[:space:]]uti:' | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 7):

You can build your own graph with UTIsExplorer https://github.com/nst/UTIsExplorer

The project includes a graph of all UTIs on my machine: http://seriot.ch/resources/utis_graph/utis_graph.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Full list of UTI types is available here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1

Comment: This list seems to be missing a lot.  Eg, CSV:  public.comma-separated-values-text