# Check if an OS X app exists to open a particular file

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is there any way to check if a user has an app installed on their Mac? I need to check if the user has a necessary program anywhere to open a file with a particular extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List/Search all existing UTIs (Uniform Type Identifiers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554187/list-search-all-existing-utis-uniform-type-identifiers)

Comment: Also see: [Is it possible to query the launch services database for applications that will open an arbitrary file or UTI type?](https://superuser.com/q/323599)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `NSWorkspace`. See the section *Manipulating Uniform Type Identifier Information* about getting and converting file extensions into uniform type identifiers, then discover what applications support those identifiers.

But if you just want to see if a file can be opened by an application and what the application is, use `-URLForApplicationToOpenURL:`.

If you want a list of all applications that can open a file, you'll have to drop down the launch services API: `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL`